# How do I extract the email address using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the email address of each restaurant on TripAdvisor.

I've tried this but keeps returning an [ ]:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class= "restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLink--iyzJI restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__contactItem--89flT6"]')
```

Code snippet off the TripAdvisor page is below:

```js
<div class="restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLink--iyzJI restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__contactItem--1flT6"><span><a href="mailto:info@canopylounge.my?subject=?"><span class="ui_icon email restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkIcon--T_k32"></span><span class="restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkText--co3ei">Email</span><span class="ui_icon external-link-no-box restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__upLinkIcon--1oVn1"></span></a></span></div>
```

Comment: first check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add this link. Scrapy can't run JavaScript. It would need Selenium to control web browser which runs JavaScript.

Comment: next check if you correctly wrote class name. I found mistake in your class name at the end `--89flT6`. Or maybe page uses different class names for every element.

Comment: [<Selector xpath='//*[@class= "restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLink--iyzJI restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__contactItem--1flT6"]/span' data='<span><div class="_2wKz--mA" data-enc...'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class= "restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLink--iyzJI restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__contactItem--1flT6"]/span' data='<span><a href="mailto:info@canopyloun...'>]

Comment: Got this but when i try to access @href it returns [] again

Comment: try `.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href')`

Comment: you was searching `<div>` but `@href` is in `<a>`. And `<a>` is not directly after `<div>`

Comment: Thank you so much response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href').extract_first() worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you had mistake in class name.

Second: it is class in `<div>` but `@href` is in `<a>`. And `<a>` is not directly after `<div>` so you need

```
'//*[@class="..."]//a/@href'
```

(I skip class name because it is too long to display it)

---

But instead of so long class name you can try

```
'//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href'
```

---

I tested `xpath` using `lxml`

```
text = '''<div class="restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLink--iyzJI restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__contactItem--1flT6">
<span><a href="mailto:info@canopylounge.my?subject=?">
<span class="ui_icon email restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkIcon--T_k32"></span>
<span class="restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLinkText--co3ei">Email</span>
<span class="ui_icon external-link-no-box restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__upLinkIcon--1oVn1"></span>
</a></span>
</div>'''

import lxml.html

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(text)

print(soup.xpath('//*[@class="restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__detailLink--iyzJI restaurants-detail-overview-cards-LocationOverviewCard__contactItem--1flT6"]//a/@href'))
print(soup.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Selector` also has a `.re()` method for extracting data using regular expressions.

```
In [2]: response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href')
Out[2]: [<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href' data='mailto:info@coinopsf.com?subject=?'>]

In [3]: response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href').get()
Out[3]: 'mailto:info@coinopsf.com?subject=?'

In [4]: response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href').re('mailto:(.*)\?\w')
Out[4]: ['info@coinopsf.com']
In [5]: response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href').re('mailto:([^?]*)')
Out[5]: ['info@coinopsf.com']
```

Comment: Slightly shorter `.re('mailto:([^?]*)')`.

Comment: Thank. Added your option

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the ways how you can:

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

site_link = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g60713-d11882449-Reviews-Coin_Op_Game_Room-San_Francisco_California.html'

res = requests.get(site_link)
sel = Selector(res)
email = sel.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'LocationOverviewCard__contactItem--')]//a[contains(@href,'mailto:')]/@href").get()
email = email.split("mailto:")[1].split("?")[0] if email else ""
print(email)
```

Output:

```
info@coinopsf.com
```