# Getting KeyError: 'link' when trying to scraping TripAdvisor for email addresses

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my code so far and should scrape the links, restaurant names and their email addresses. Everything was working fine up until I added in the email, even though it returned the email addresses

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request


class RestaurantSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'restaurant'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com.my/Restaurants-g298570-Kuala_Lumpur_Wilayah_Persekutuan.html#EATERY_OVERVIEW_BOX']
```

`def parse` is where i gather all the listings from the main page then go through each page accessing each restaurant page

```
    def parse(self, response):
        listings = response.xpath(
            '//div[@class="restaurants-list-ListCell__cellContainer--2mpJS"]')

        for listing in listings:
            link = listing.xpath(
                './/a[@class="restaurants-list-ListCell__restaurantName--2aSdo"]/@href').extract_first()
            text = listing.xpath(
                './/a[@class="restaurants-list-ListCell__restaurantName--2aSdo"]/text()').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(link),
                                 callback=self.parse_listing,
                                 meta={
                                     'Link': link,
                                     'Text': text
            }
            )

        next_urls = response.xpath(
            '//*[@class="nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk"]/@href').extract()
        for next_url in next_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_url), callback=self.parse)
```

`def parse_listing` is where i access the email of a specific restaurant and then yield the required data which will be later stored into a .csv file

```
    def parse_listing(self, response):
        link = response.meta['link']
        text = response.meta['text']

        email = response.xpath(
            '//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href').extract_first()

        yield {
            'Link': link,
            'Text': text,
            'Email': email
        }
```

Comment: please include the complete error message.

Comment: did you inspected response.meta??

Comment: @Sureshmani line 33, in parse_listing
    link = response.meta['link']
KeyError: 'link'

Comment: What about your [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426462/how-do-i-extract-the-email-address-using-scrapy) which appears to have been solved but you didn't select any answer out of three?

Comment: @SIM I did use one of the answers in ```email = response.xpath(
            '//a[contains(@href, "mailto")]/@href').extract_first()```

Comment: Check out ***[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)*** to understand what I meant @yuRa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `meta={'Link':link,'Text':text}` within `parse()` method but you are calling wrong key `link` within `parse_listing()` method to get it's value which causes the error. Your xpaths are error prone.

Try like the following to get it working:

```
class RestaurantSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'restaurant'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com.my/Restaurants-g298570-Kuala_Lumpur_Wilayah_Persekutuan.html#EATERY_OVERVIEW_BOX'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for listing in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"__cellContainer--")]'):
            link = listing.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"__restaurantName--")]/@href').get()
            text = listing.xpath('.//a[contains(@class,"__restaurantName--")]/text()').get()
            complete_url = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=complete_url,
                callback=self.parse_listing,
                meta={'link': complete_url,'text': text}
            )

        next_url = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"pagination")]/*[contains(@class,"next")]/@href').get()
        if next_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_url), callback=self.parse)

    def parse_listing(self, response):
        link = response.meta['link']
        text = response.meta['text']
        email = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "mailto:")]/@href').get()
        yield {'Link': link,'Text': text,'Email': email}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'link' by 'href'

Cant reproduce your code, but dont seems to be a link attribute.... so catch "href"

```
<a href="/Restaurant_Review-g298570-d15211507-Reviews-Vintage_1988_Cafe-Kuala_Lumpur_Wilayah_Persekutuan.html" class="restaurants-list-ListCell__restaurantName--2aSdo" target="_blank">Vintage 1988 Cafe</a>


link = response.meta['href']
```

Comment: this error appears ```line 33, in parse_listing
    link = response.meta['href']
KeyError: 'href'```

Comment: I will re-post my question that you ignored, 
did you inspected response.meta??

Comment: sorry about that but what do you mean by inspecting it?